# Save Image to particular folder from Openfiledialog?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to save images to my project folder from openfiledialog result . I don't get foler path to save . How do I get folder path ? How do I save that ? Please Help me.

Comment: You don't. You use the `SaveFileDialog` to save files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello thinzar,

```
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap();
        this.saveFileDialog1.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
        if (this.saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            myBitmap.Save(this.saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
      }
```

Bye

Answer (score 3):

[FileDialog.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) gives the full path to the file. And btw it is probably easier to use the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) because you want to save something, not open.

Answer (score 1):

Something alone these lines

```
Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap();

// draw on the image

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog ();
if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   myImage.Save(sfd.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) allows the user to select a folder. Maybe that would be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're opening a file elsewhere and then using the results to later save stuff into the directory you opened from?

```
DialogResult result = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
  string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
  // directoryName now contains the path
}
```